# Why proxy in React app doesn't work when I use fetch('/')?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy

When I tried to connect React front-end to Node back-end I faced some connection problems, because these applications used different ports. Then I found out, that solution is using proxy on the front-end side (i.e. having string `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` in package.json). However, that didn't work for me -- all solutions from Google didn't help at all.

And then I found out that actually proxy works, but I tried to fetch data from root address of backend application (i.e. using `fetch('/')` in some lines of code) and it returned the data from root directory of front-end application. Adding extra directory in fetch function made it work properly -- for example, `fetch('/api')` finally returned data from back-end application.

So, the question is why is it so? What's the logic lies behind fetch and proxy, which deactivate proxy, while fetching from root address?